# How can I wait for an item to become visible, then disappear?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a pure JavaScript function (no jQuery) that will:
1. Wait for a DOC element to become visible.
2. Wait for the same element to then become invisible.
Here is my current attempt:

```
var checkVisible = setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('submitBusy');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    /* See if element is visible. */
    if (style.display !== 'none') {
        clearInterval(checkVisible);

        var checkInvisible = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById('submitBusy');
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
            /* See if element is visible. */
            if (style.display === 'none') {
                clearInterval(checkInvisible);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
}, 50);
```

On the page, when a certain button is clicked to load a table on the page, the following function is called:

```
function searchStart() {
    $("#submitBusy").css("display", "inline-block");
}
```

once the page's contents are pulled from the server, the following is called:

```
function searchDone() {
    $("#submitBusy").css("display", "none");
}
```

Once the "submitBusy" element is shown and then disappears, I then want to walk through all rows in the newly generated table so I need to know where to put that code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A custom event might be a cleaner way to respond when the `submitBusy` element disappears.
If you want to try this way see the code (and comments) in the snippet below.

In this demo, the custom event, called `removedEvent`, bubbles up and is listened for by `document`, although any ancestor of `submitBusy` could just as easily have the eventListener attached instead.
(The button in the demo code is just there to simulate the completion of your table data loading.)

```js
// Adds event listener to demo button to simulate end of loading
const removeBtn = document.querySelector("#removeBtn");
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", simulateEndOfLoading);

// Function that runs when table data is loaded
function simulateEndOfLoading() {
  const submitBusy = document.querySelector("#submitBusy");
  submitBusy.style.display = "none";
  submitBusy.dispatchEvent(removedEvent); // Triggers custom event
}

// Defines custom event
const removedEvent = new CustomEvent("removedEvent", {bubbles: true});

// Listens for custom event
document.addEventListener("removedEvent", respondToRemovedEvent);

// The #submitBusy element is gone, and we can respond accordingly 
function respondToRemovedEvent(e){
  console.log("The thing happened")
}
```

```css
#removeBtn { box-shadow: 1px 1px grey; }
#submitBusy{ width: 15ch; margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<button id="removeBtn">Simuate end of loading</button>
<div id="submitBusy">loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be much easier to add the code into your `searchDone` function...but if there is some reason why you **must** watch for the element to be shown and then hidden, the most efficient way would be to use an [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Detecting when elements "intersect" with the current viewport (or other elements) is what it's for, and of course this includes things like scrolling into view or changing the display of the element.

But even though it would theoretically work, you'd be much better off using a custom event as @cat suggested, or even just a regular function call in `searchDone`.

```js
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
let hasShown = false;
let hasHidden = false;
function callback(entries) {
  entries.forEach(e => {
    if (e.isIntersecting) hasShown = true;
    else if (hasShown) hasHidden = true;
    if (hasShown &&  hasHidden) console.log('shown and hidden, do something!');
  });
}

let target = document.querySelector('#submitBusy');
observer.observe(target);

setTimeout(() => {
  target.style.display = 'block';
}, 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  target.style.display = 'none';
}, 1500);
```

```html
<div id='submitBusy' style="display:none;">please wait...</div>
```

You'd want to check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver) to verify it's acceptable to you. Coverage is currently 92.8%.